# understanding the following derivation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand how my professor did the following integral
$\int_{\omega} \frac{1}{z} dz = 2\pi * i$,

where $\omega$ := unit circle, transversed once in a clockwise direction.

Consider $\int_{\omega} \frac{1}{z} dz = 2\pi * i$. Consider $\omega : [0,2\pi] : \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $\omega(t) = cos(t) + isin(t)$.

Hence the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{-sin(t) + icos(t)}{cos(t) + isin(t)} dt$, but I can't solve this further. When I simplify it in wolf ram alpha it gives i, which will get the result above, but it doesn't show the derivation if someone could show it to me it would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factor out $i$:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-\sin(t)+i\cos(t)}{\cos(t)+i\sin(t)} dt = \int_0^{2\pi} i\cdot\frac{i\sin(t)+\cos(t)}{\cos(t)+i\sin(t)} dt = i\int_0^{2\pi}dt = 2\pi i$$

Answer (score 2):

On the unit circle $|z|=1$, we have $z=e^{i\theta}$, thus 
$$(1/z)\mathrm{d}z=e^{-i\theta}e^{i\theta}i\mathrm{d}\theta=i\mathrm{d}\theta$$

$$\int_{\omega} \frac{1}{z} dz = \int_0^{2\pi}i\mathrm{d}\theta=2\pi i$$